# Microeconomics Question on Trade

Tags: microeconomics

What ensures that goods and services will get from those who should be producing them to those who should be consuming them?

This a textbook question but I'm not sure to answer to this.

Comment: Who determines "*who should be consuming*" a good?

Answer (score 0):

Without context, this is impossible to answer. Usually, the answer would be something like a relative price/market price. It will indicate whether the opportunity cost of the good is lower than than the marginal utility derived by the consumer and whether its price is larger than the marginal costs of producing the good.